# Facebook PHP API Search, Sort by friends first

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am searching through users using Facebook PHP API, as below:

```
$fb_friends = $this->facebook->api('/search?q=polo&type=user&fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,location,picture.width(215)');
```

Is it possible to have the returned users sorted by Friends first? If not, how can I retrieve my friends using the API ('/me/friends/'), but only the ones that match my query string 'polo' ? Is this possible without FQL?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're avoiding FQL?

Answer (score 1):

FQL is a handy way to get results the way you want. An example of getting your friends and then ordering them by last name follows:

```
$fql = "{\"q1\":\"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()\",";
$fql .= "\"q2\":\"SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM #q1) ORDER BY last_name ASC\"}";
$fqlurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".urlencode($fql)."&access_token=".$fbtoken;
$fqr = file_get_contents($fqlurl);
$fq = json_decode($fqr, true);
$friends = $fq['data'][1]['fql_result_set'];
```

Facebook's [FQL Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) is a decent place to start if you want to learn more about FQL. While they do a decent job explaining the query syntax, their example code kind of just throws a lot of code at you though without really breaking it down, but what I have above is really the essence of it. Let me know if this is what you're looking for, and if you have any questions :)

Comment: I have no problem with FQL actually, just would have preferred the simpler alternative. Why are you putting uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM #q1) ? Doesn't this make the second query retrieve only my friends?

Comment: It returns the the names and uid of the friends whose id's are retrieved in the first query. In my example, the first query retrieves the id's of your friends (the table only has id's, no names), but you can replace `me()` with a php variable to retrieve whoever's friends you want to list.